# open multiple subfolders and copy all excel files in it to another folder- VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a code with VBA that should do the following:

I have a folder Para that contains 5 folders: Tata, Tete, Tutu, Toto, Titi
I want to open Para, then open Tata and copy all excel folders in it then open Tete and copy all the Excel folders etc.. until the last one Titi.
I want them all in one folder Para_Copy! 
Is there a code that can do that?

I have a code (but desn't work) on one folder only:

```
Sub sbCopyingAFile()
    'Declare Variables
    Dim FSO
    Dim sFile As String
    Dim sSFolder As String
    Dim sDFolder As String
    Dim myfile

    'This is Your File Name which you want to Copy
    sFile = "*.xls*"
    'Change to match the source folder path
    sSFolder = "Z:\Base_de_données\PARA\Toto\"
    ''Target Path with Ending Extention
    myfile = Dir(sSFolder & sFile)
    'Change to match the destination folder path
    sDFolder = "Z:\Base_de_données\Para_Copy"

    Do While myfile <> ""

        'Create Object
        Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

        'Checking If File Is Located in the Source Folder
        If Not FSO.FileExists(myfile) Then
            MsgBox "Specified File Not Found", vbInformation, "Not Found"

        'Copying If the Same File is Not Located in the Destination Folder
        ElseIf Not FSO.FileExists(sDFolder & sFile) Then
            FSO.CopyFile (myfile), sDFolder, True
            MsgBox "Specified File Copied Successfully", vbInformation, "Done!"

        Else
            MsgBox "Specified File Already Exists In The Destination Folder", _
                vbExclamation, "File Already Exists"

        End If

        myfile = Dir()

    Loop

End Sub
```

Thank you for your help!
Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to copy ther files, and not data from the files, right.  If I were you, I would list all the files in all the folders, and subfolders.

```
Sub GetFolder_Data_Collection()

Range("A:L").ClearContents
Range("A1").Value = "Name"
Range("B1").Value = "Path"
Range("C1").Value = "Size (KB)"
Range("D1").Value = "DateLastModified"
Range("E1").Value = "Attributes"
Range("F1").Value = "DateCreated"
Range("G1").Value = "DateLastAccessed"
Range("H1").Value = "Drive"
Range("I1").Value = "ParentFolder"
Range("J1").Value = "ShortName"
Range("K1").Value = "ShortPath"
Range("L1").Value = "Type"
Range("A1").Select

Dim strPath As String
'strPath = "I:\Information Security\KRI Monthly Data Collection\"
strPath = GetFolder

Dim OBJ As Object, Folder As Object, File As Object

Set OBJ = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Folder = OBJ.GetFolder(strPath)

Call ListFiles(Folder)

Dim SubFolder As Object

For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
    Call ListFiles(SubFolder)
    Call GetSubFolders(SubFolder)
Next SubFolder


End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Sub ListFiles(ByRef Folder As Object)

On Error Resume Next
For Each File In Folder.Files
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveCell = File.Name
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = File.Path
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0), Address:=File.Path, TextToDisplay:=File.Path
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) = (File.Size / 1024) 'IN KB
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3) = File.DateLastModified
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4) = File.Attributes
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5) = File.DateCreated
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6) = File.DateLastAccessed
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7) = File.Drive
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8) = File.ParentFolder
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9) = File.ShortName
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10) = File.ShortPath
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11) = File.Type
Next File

End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Sub GetSubFolders(ByRef SubFolder As Object)

Dim FolderItem As Object
On Error Resume Next
For Each FolderItem In SubFolder.SubFolders
    Call ListFiles(FolderItem)
    Call GetSubFolders(FolderItem)
Next FolderItem

End Sub


Function GetFolder() As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

Then, run a small script to do the copy/paste stuff.  The 'FromPath' comes from the paths you generated using the script above and the 'ToPath' will be whatever you choose.

```
Sub Copy_Folder()
'This example copy all files and subfolders from FromPath to ToPath.
'Note: If ToPath already exist it will overwrite existing files in this folder
'if ToPath not exist it will be made for you.
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim FromPath As String
    Dim ToPath As String

    FromPath = "C:\Users\Ron\Data"  '<< Change
    ToPath = "C:\Users\Ron\Test"    '<< Change

    'If you want to create a backup of your folder every time you run this macro
    'you can create a unique folder with a Date/Time stamp.
    'ToPath = "C:\Users\Ron\" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd h-mm-ss")

    If Right(FromPath, 1) = "\" Then
        FromPath = Left(FromPath, Len(FromPath) - 1)
    End If

    If Right(ToPath, 1) = "\" Then
        ToPath = Left(ToPath, Len(ToPath) - 1)
    End If

    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    If FSO.FolderExists(FromPath) = False Then
        MsgBox FromPath & " doesn't exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    FSO.CopyFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath
    MsgBox "You can find the files and subfolders from " & FromPath & " in " & ToPath

End Sub
```

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win026.htm

Comment: Wow thank you so much! I will run it and let you know